# Building Emacs from trunk without admin access

Tags: compiling, emacs

I cloned the official `trunk` branch with:

```
bzr branch bzr://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/emacs/trunk
```

I then built `autoconf`, `automake` and `texinfo`. I also updated my `PERL5LIB` to make it include `/path/to/automake/share/automake-1.13` (otherwise I get the error: `can't locate Automake/Config.pm`).

I then run:

```
> autogen.sh
```

I then run `./configure --without-gif --prefix=/some/path`.

I then run `make` and get  the following error: `collect2: error: ld returned exit status`. See the full trace below:

```
gcc -std=gnu99     -I. -I../src -I../lib -I/home/john/bin/emacs/rc/emacs-24.3/lib-src -I/home/john/opt/emacs/rc/emacs-24.3/lib-src/../src -I/home/
john/bin/emacs/rc/emacs-24.3/lib-src/../lib  -Wl,-znocombreloc   -g3 -O2 -DEMACS_NAME="\"GNU Emacs\"" \
          -DVERSION="\"24.3\"" /home/john/bin/emacs/rc/emacs-24.3/lib-src/etags.c \
          regex.o ../lib/libgnu.a  -o etags
regex.o: In function `stpncpy':
/usr/include/bits/string3.h:160: multiple definition of `stpncpy'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/string3.h:160: first defined here
regex.o: In function `realpath':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:37: multiple definition of `realpath'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:37: first defined here
regex.o: In function `ptsname_r':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:53: multiple definition of `ptsname_r'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:53: first defined here
regex.o: In function `wctomb':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:74: multiple definition of `wctomb'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:74: first defined here
regex.o: In function `mbstowcs':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:95: multiple definition of `mbstowcs'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:95: first defined here
regex.o: In function `wcstombs':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:114: multiple definition of `wcstombs'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:114: first defined here
regex.o: In function `read':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:35: multiple definition of `read'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:35: first defined here
regex.o: In function `pread':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:57: multiple definition of `pread'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:57: first defined here
regex.o: In function `pread64':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:77: multiple definition of `pread64'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:77: first defined here
regex.o: In function `readlink':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:99: multiple definition of `readlink'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:99: first defined here
regex.o: In function `readlinkat':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:121: multiple definition of `readlinkat'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:121: first defined here
regex.o: In function `getcwd':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:136: multiple definition of `getcwd'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:136: first defined here
regex.o: In function `getwd':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:150: multiple definition of `getwd'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:150: first defined here
regex.o: In function `confstr':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:165: multiple definition of `confstr'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:165: first defined here
regex.o: In function `getgroups':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:181: multiple definition of `getgroups'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:181: first defined here
regex.o: In function `ttyname_r':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:197: multiple definition of `ttyname_r'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:197: first defined here
regex.o: In function `getlogin_r':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:213: multiple definition of `getlogin_r'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:213: first defined here
regex.o: In function `gethostname':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:230: multiple definition of `gethostname'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:230: first defined here
regex.o: In function `getdomainname':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:248: multiple definition of `getdomainname'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:248: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(c-strcasecmp.o): In function `stpncpy':
/usr/include/bits/string3.h:160: multiple definition of `stpncpy'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/string3.h:160: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(c-strcasecmp.o): In function `realpath':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:37: multiple definition of `realpath'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:37: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(c-strcasecmp.o): In function `ptsname_r':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:53: multiple definition of `ptsname_r'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:53: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(c-strcasecmp.o): In function `wctomb':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:74: multiple definition of `wctomb'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:74: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(c-strcasecmp.o): In function `mbstowcs':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:95: multiple definition of `mbstowcs'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:95: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(c-strcasecmp.o): In function `wcstombs':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:114: multiple definition of `wcstombs'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:114: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(c-strncasecmp.o): In function `stpncpy':
/usr/include/bits/string3.h:160: multiple definition of `stpncpy'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/string3.h:160: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(c-strncasecmp.o): In function `realpath':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:37: multiple definition of `realpath'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:37: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(c-strncasecmp.o): In function `ptsname_r':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:53: multiple definition of `ptsname_r'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:53: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(c-strncasecmp.o): In function `wctomb':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:74: multiple definition of `wctomb'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:74: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(c-strncasecmp.o): In function `mbstowcs':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:95: multiple definition of `mbstowcs'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:95: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(c-strncasecmp.o): In function `wcstombs':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:114: multiple definition of `wcstombs'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:114: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `stpncpy':
/usr/include/bits/string3.h:160: multiple definition of `stpncpy'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/string3.h:160: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `realpath':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:37: multiple definition of `realpath'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:37: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `ptsname_r':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:53: multiple definition of `ptsname_r'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:53: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `wctomb':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:74: multiple definition of `wctomb'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:74: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `mbstowcs':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:95: multiple definition of `mbstowcs'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:95: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `wcstombs':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:114: multiple definition of `wcstombs'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:114: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `gets':
/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:94: multiple definition of `gets'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:94: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `fgets':
/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:109: multiple definition of `fgets'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:109: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `fgets_unlocked':
/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:125: multiple definition of `fgets_unlocked'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:125: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `read':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:35: multiple definition of `read'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:35: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `pread':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:57: multiple definition of `pread'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:57: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `pread64':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:77: multiple definition of `pread64'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:77: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `readlink':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:99: multiple definition of `readlink'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:99: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `readlinkat':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:121: multiple definition of `readlinkat'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:121: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `getcwd':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:136: multiple definition of `getcwd'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:136: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `getwd':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:150: multiple definition of `getwd'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:150: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `confstr':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:165: multiple definition of `confstr'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:165: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `getgroups':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:181: multiple definition of `getgroups'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:181: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `ttyname_r':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:197: multiple definition of `ttyname_r'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:197: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `getlogin_r':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:213: multiple definition of `getlogin_r'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:213: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `gethostname':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:230: multiple definition of `gethostname'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:230: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt.o): In function `getdomainname':
/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:248: multiple definition of `getdomainname'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/unistd.h:248: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt1.o): In function `stpncpy':
/usr/include/bits/string3.h:160: multiple definition of `stpncpy'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/string3.h:160: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt1.o): In function `realpath':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:37: multiple definition of `realpath'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:37: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt1.o): In function `ptsname_r':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:53: multiple definition of `ptsname_r'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:53: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt1.o): In function `wctomb':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:74: multiple definition of `wctomb'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:74: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt1.o): In function `mbstowcs':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:95: multiple definition of `mbstowcs'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:95: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt1.o): In function `wcstombs':
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:114: multiple definition of `wcstombs'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h:114: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt1.o): In function `gets':
/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:94: multiple definition of `gets'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:94: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt1.o): In function `fgets':
/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:109: multiple definition of `fgets'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:109: first defined here
../lib/libgnu.a(getopt1.o): In function `fgets_unlocked':
/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:125: multiple definition of `fgets_unlocked'
/tmp/ccntBfBN.o:/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:125: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [etags] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/james/bin/emacs/rc/emacs-24.3/lib-src'
make: *** [lib-src] Error 2
```

Any thougths?

Comment: Why did you build those? They _are_ packaged by all distributions.

Comment: @vonbrand. The one in my distro was too old, and I don't have rood priviledges.

Comment: You are in for a whole world of pain... emacs depends on all sort of weird pieces being available to build it. As you saw, development tools, all sort of libraries (and the development headers), ... I never built emacs without root, never tried to install it outside `/usr` or `/usr/local`, and even that wasn't exactly trivial (it sure got better in the last 12 or so years, but still...)

Comment: Thanks @vonbrand. I managed to get pass those first few errors, but I am now stack with an odd `ld error`.. (I updated the OP)

Comment: Need the exact error message(s). emacs does some _very_ funny business to create an object containing compiled emacs LISP code...

Answer (score 4):

You need to run `autoreconf` to create the whole machinery (the checkout from a VCS won't contain any generated files, the distributed tarballs contain them for convenience/crippled environments).

Comment: The `autogen.sh` file will run `autoreconf` for you with the proper options `autoreconf -i -I m4`

Comment: Thanks @jordanm. I built `autoconf` and `automake` (I don't have admin priviledges), but now I get the error "`can't locate Automake/Config.pm`", which I believe is a  Perl module. I have Perl installed and use it relatively often. Is this something that I can get from CPAN?

Comment: It's part of automake. You may need to set your PERL5LIB to the location of your automake installation.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm and vobrand. I now have a configure error when running `./configure`. It asks for `libXaw`. I do want to run Emacs with X window support (i.e. not just run Emacs from within a terminal). Any thoughts?

Comment: run "./configure --help" and read all the options. There is probably one to enable/disable Xaw (athena widgets), and another to specify Xaw location. I think you can safely drop Xaw.